# Execute an append on button click in materialize modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, append, materialize

I am using Materialize modal and I have a form and two buttons in it, "Validate" and "Cancel".
When I click on "Validate" I wish to generate a div in the body of the page but the div appear and disappear as quickly.

Next my code using jquery :

```
$('#validation-btn').click(function(){
   $("#liste-questions").append("<div>hello world</div>");
});
```

And the code in HTML page :

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="liste-questions" class="liste-questions row">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-btn-bottom">
    <a href="#modal1" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light btn add"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <form class="col s12" id="formQuestions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="intitule" data-champ="intitule" name="intitule" type="text" class="validate requis">
                <label for="intitule">Intitulé <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <p class="help-block" id="help-intitule"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="ref" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="ref">Ref</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <textarea id="description" class="materialize-textarea" class="validate"></textarea>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-right">
            <button type="submit" id="validation-btn" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-large validation">Créer</button>
            <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-large cancel">Annuler</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/form-validation.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
});
</script>
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rep for comments, so Ill write an "answer". Your code should indeed append a div to your body. Most likely the problem is in the styling. Try running your code and set the CSS manualy through your browser dev tools until it looks as you want it to look. Then just add the styles in your JS code.

Comment: Thank youI did not add any CSS yet!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "document.body" rather than "body" and the quotes should be removed

```
$('#validation-btn').click(function(){
   $(document.body).append("<div>hello world</div>");
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't resolve the problem. I tried to insert div in other div with an id too but the problem persist

Comment: are you trying to add the div element to the form before form submit?

Comment: No when I submit form i would like to close modal and add a div in body/other div in document body.

Comment: You can prevent your button click function and use "dismissible: false" to close modal and add you div to the document then submit the form